# how to get python dictionary first item value in variable

Tags: python, dictionary, show

## Program

```
import pyowm
import pandas as pd

OWM=pyowm.OWM('ccb59666571a5e0bfe146f92ddf8e24f')
observation = OWM.weather_at_coords(19.997454,73.7898)
w = observation.get_weather()

temperature = w.get_temperature('celsius')

print(temperature)
for k,v in temperature.items()
  temp1=v[0]
```

## Output

> {'temp': 22.47, 'temp_max': 22.47, 'temp_min': 22.47, 'temp_kf': None}

From this output I just want to get value of first item in any variable for further use. i.e 22.47

It gives me this error message:

> "float' object is not subscriptable python"

Comment: Are you using python3.6?

Comment: So you want 2 as an output from 22.47. Is it?

Comment: What it "value of first item in any variable" supposed to mean ??? You have a dict of `str`:`float` pairs, if you want the value for the "temp" key all you need is `temperature['temp']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for is to be able to print out `temp` or `temp_max` and so on individually.

The way you'd do this is to reference the index of the element you want to print.

```
# Lists
listName.index(0) # This would give the very first item in the list.
listName.index(len(listName) - 1) # This would give you the very last item in the list.

# Dictionaries (the one you're using for temperature)
dictionaryName['indexName'] # This would give you the item under indexName.
temperature['temp_max'] # This would give you the item under temp_max!
```

Dictionaries work in the same way to real life ones. When you look up a word, which we know as an index, it gives us some information. In the case of python, we specify the dictionary and then put the index into the square brackets.

```
# For the different values in the temperature dictionary...
temperature['temp'] #This is the value of 'temp' in dictionary temperature
temperature['temp_max'] #This is the value of 'temp_max' in dictionary temperature
temperature['temp_min'] #This is the value of 'temp_min' in dictionary temperature
temperature['temp_kf'] #This is the value of 'temp_kf' in dictionary temperature
```

To then print these out individually, you'd use the same method as printing variables!

[A dirty big page of documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) may help! :D